# ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET does not work for FireDAC in DELPHI 10.3.1

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac, delphi-10.3-rio

After attaching the second database I tried to insert and update data in the table of the first database using ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE. Field id is the primary key for the first table.

```
  FDQuery1.EXECSQL('ATTACH ''D:\Update2019.DB'' AS DBUpdate');

  FDQuery1.SQL.Text:=
    'INSERT INTO acts (id,title) SELECT id,title FROM DBUpdate.acts'+
    '   WHERE (DBUpdate.acts.id >100)'+
    '   ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET'+
    '   title=excluded.title;'
  FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

I get error message: "ERROR near "ON":syntax error"
When I removed  WHERE (DBUpdate.acts.id >100 condition
the error message AS: "ERROR near "DO":syntax error".

The same query works fine in SQLITESTUDIO.

Comment: Is your version of SQLite at least 3.24.0?

Comment: How can I get the version of sqlite in delphi 10.3.1

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#sqlite_version

Comment: version is 3.23.1 - how i can change the version to 3.24 or the latest one  in delphi 10.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As correctly indicated in comments, SQLite that your application uses does not support this syntax. You will need to use newer version of SQLite. To do this, follow the **Dynamic linking** paragraph of [`FireDAC SQLite connection`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Connect_to_SQLite_database_(FireDAC)#Client_Software) topic, otherwise Delphi builds your FireDAC application with statically linked SQLite objects of the version distributed with it (which makes your application dependent on such SQLite version no matter what SQLite DLLs are all around).

Just don't forget the most **important** part of this task; modifying the **FireDAC.inc** include file to use dynamic linking. If you don't want to break your Delphi setup source folder, copy for example all the FireDAC modules somewhere else, add them into the build search path of your project, and modify the **FireDAC.inc** include file there.

Comment: Thanks TLama. There is one no for me to use dynamic linking. "Note: SQLite database encryption is supported only for static linking.". So I've to find another solution instead of "insert ... ON CONFLICT(id) DO"